# Create a new list based on pattern matching in another list

Tags: python, python-re

I have a list of strings and I want to check for a pattern and combine two elements together if the pattern matches and create a new list.

For example, this is my list:

```
string_ = ["aBc", "ab","12abc55", "ABAB", "125"]
```

How - if the 2nd item in the list is a string ( with no numbers inside ) and the 3rd item in the list is combination of numbers and chars then I want to add them together with a space in between. My final output should be:

```
["aBc", "ab 12abc55", "ABAB", "125"]
```

I have tried the below:

```
    def hasNumbers(inputString):
        return bool(re.search(r'\d', inputString))

    data = []
    for i in range (0,len(string_)):


            if string_[1].isalnum() and hasNumbers(string_[2]):
                data.append(string_[1]+ " "+ string_[2])
            else:
                data.append(string_[i])
```

This does not give the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you want to use a loop, you need to use `i` to read the list's values:

```
import re
string_ = ["aBc", "ab", "12abc55", "ABAB", "125", "aBc", "ab", "12abc55", "ABAB", "125"]

def hasNumbers(inputString):
    return bool(re.search(r'\d', inputString))

for i in range (0, len(string_)-1):
    if string_[i].isalnum() and hasNumbers(string_[i+1]):
        data.append(string_[i]+ " "+ string_[i+1])
    else:
        data.append(string_[i])
print(data)
```

Output:

```
['aBc', 'ab 12abc55', '12abc55', 'ABAB 125', '125', 'aBc', 'ab 12abc55', '12abc55', 'ABAB 125']
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over the list with the for loop has no sense here because  the operation you want to do has to be done only once. So you don't need a loop. You could replace the for loop with these to achieve the expected result:

```
a,b,c,d = string_
if b.isalnum() and hasNumbers(c):
        data = [a, b + ' ' +  c, d]
else:
    data = string_
```

Answer (score 1):

I would copy the whole list and update it only if the condition meets
for the second and the third elements:

```py
import re

string_ = ["aBc", "ab", "12abc55", "ABAB", "125"]


def hasNumbers(inputString):
    return bool(re.search(r'\d', inputString))


data = string_.copy()
if data[1].isalnum() and hasNumbers(data[2]):
    data[1] += f' {data.pop(2)}'

print(data)
```

```py
['aBc', 'ab 12abc55', 'ABAB', '125']
```